# KMeans in Python centroids not in correct position, how do I "unscale" them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a small script to run in a jupyter notebook. The Kmeans seems to be working correctly, but my centroids are scaled down. How do I get them to display correctly on my plot? My x and y range from 0 to about 500 on each side.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import pandas as pd

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
df = pd.read_csv("sales-by-week-4.csv")
df2 = DataFrame(df,columns=["Average Sale Price", "Average Weekly"])
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(scale(df2))
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroids)

plt.scatter(df2["Average Weekly"], df2["Average Sale Price"], c= kmeans.labels_.astype(float), s=50, alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], c='red', s=50)
```

Here's my centroid print.

```
[[ 2.65044538 -0.37653707]
 [-0.64002758 -0.25885017]
 [-0.39559393  5.26965425]
 [ 0.91316601 -0.29410492]
 [-0.5276885   0.8949181 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You fitted KMeans on your scaled dataframe. Try to fit on `df2` only